# Netflix streaming - get current timestamp of video that is playing

Tags: silverlight, netflix

i am looking to get the current timestamp and/or frame number for a streaming netflix (or other Silverlight) video that is currently playing in my browser.

is there a way to do this programmatically (my current solution involves scraping and parsing the current time from the playhead area)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27927950/32453